# Making a mini vertical divider

Tags: html, css, node.js

I am trying to make a miniature vertical bar like in [this](http://nodejs.org) site, where they have the navigation and the vertical bars in between each link. I have tried the solution to a previous question, but when I tried to use 'margin-left' to move the text, the bar wouldn't stay between each link, it'd to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5qZz.jpg).

HTML

```
<div id="nav-clearfix">
    <div id="nav">
        <ul class="nav-pages">
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><div class="mini-divider"></div></li>
            <li><a href="#">ROSTER</a></li>
            <li><div class="mini-divider"></div></li>
            <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
            <li><div class="mini-divider"></div></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><div class="mini-divider"></div></li>
            <li><a href="#">SPONSORS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav-clearfix {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}

#nav {
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-pages {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.mini-divider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 26%;
    bottom: 71%;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}

.nav-pages li, .mini-divider {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***CSS***

```
.nav-pages li:not(:last-child) a:after{
  content: "";
  /* width: 0px; */
  background: white;
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  height: inherit;
  color: white;

  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 15px;
}
```

Remove The Border Related HTML & CSS

```
<li><div class="mini-divider"></div></li>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tg2d4t16/13/)

Comment: Thanks, it works, but is there any way to get rid of the line after 'Sponsors'?

Comment: @CraftdMC just a moment

Comment: just add `.nav-pages li:not(:last-child)  a:after` it will give not take the `last-child`

Comment: or use `.nav-pages li + li a:after` and add styles to `right` side

Comment: wow, i've been looking for this for ages... thanks @KawineshSK

Comment: Np just now found it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `+` css selector to give border to the next element no need to add extra element for `border`

added

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
```

for removing default styles given by browsers

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav-clearfix {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
#nav {
  width: 100%;
}
.nav-pages {
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align:center;
}
.nav-pages li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.nav-pages li + li {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-clearfix">
  <div id="nav">
    <ul class="nav-pages">
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ROSTER</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">SPONSORS</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this .separator class for vertical separator.

***CSS***

```
 ul > li{
    float: left;
     display: block;
    position: relative;
}
ul > li > a{
    padding: 4px 6px;
    display: block;
}
 .separator {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222;
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 1px;
}
```

***HTML***

```
<ul> 
    <li >
        <a href="#" >Home</a> 
    </li> <span class="separator"></span> 
    <li> <a href="#">Link 1</a> </li> <span class="separator"></span> 
    <li > <a href="#">Link 2</a> </li> <span class="separator"></span> 
    <li> <a href="#">Link3</a> </li> <span class="separator"></span> 
    <li > <a href="#contact-us">Contact</a> </li> 
</ul>
```

[jsfiddle: demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yz0etgw9/)